# Name for $K' = \{y \in \mathbb R^m: y^T A \ge 0\}$ when $K = \{x \in \mathbb R^n: Ax \le 0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The following question came up in the context of an optimization problem.

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ be a matrix and let
$$K = \{x \in \mathbb R^n: Ax \le 0\}$$
be the polyhedral cone defined by the set of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ that make a *nonpositive* angle with each of the *rows* of $A$.

Now consider the following polyhedral cone:
$$K' = \{y \in \mathbb R^m: y^T A \ge 0\}.$$
$K'$ is the set of vectors in $\mathbb R^m$ whose angle with each of the *columns* of $A$ is *nonnegative*.

**Question**: Is there a name for $K'$? If not, what can we say about the (geometric) relation between the sets $K$ and $K'$?

Comment: $K'_A = K_{A^T}$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a term for the relationship between $K$ and $K'$. However, we can characterize $K'$ as the [dual cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_cone_and_polar_cone) to the convex cone generated by the columns of $A$. That is, $K = C^*$, where $C$ is the convex cone defined by $C = \{Ax : x \in \Bbb R^n, x \geq 0\}$.

Similarly, $K$ is the polar cone to the convex cone generated by the rows of $A$.